# Error when adding Google Mobile Ads SDK to Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, admob, google-mobile-ads

I'm encountering an issue when trying to integrate the Google Mobile Ads SDK into my Flutter project. When I add the dependency to my pubspec.yaml file and try to build the project, I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':google_mobile_ads'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.
```

`I have followed the steps outlined in the documentation and from the Youtube tutorial [video][1] but I can't seem to resolve this issue. Can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this error?`

Additional Information:

Flutter version:  3.13.1,
Android Studio version: 2022.3
Google Mobile Ads SDK version:3.0.0